# Migrating data in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, template, stp

I have an App created and deployed to SP online. The list that gets deployed with the app is empty and I need to migrate data into it. Is it possible to import a SharePoint list (.stp) into a SharePoint online App Web? If not, what is the recommended way to get List data to the cloud?

Comment: As part of the provisioning you could write the necessary data, I did that often as part of on-prem feature deployment. Create the infrastructure, then create the data. You should be able to do something similar.

Comment: Eric, do you mean Hard code the data in Elements.xml?

Comment: That is one way to do it, sure. For smaller config type lists I deployed via feature in the past, I would do that. In the app model, it could be part of your JS file, to provision the data via CSOM or REST.

Answer (score 2):

You can export the list to excel and then import it into SharePoint online list.

Also check this KB articles for more detailed information about how to manually migrate the content to the office 365.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2783484

Comment: will I be able to import the list directly to the App Web or does this method only allow importing into the Host Web?